# Only the first window is draggable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a code, where a window pops up. This window is draggable and resizable. I added a function in JavaScript, which adds two new windows when the first one is closed and adds more when the others are closed, but I also want them to be draggable as well.

I tried almost everything I know, but I don't seem to understand the issue.

```js
const windowElement = document.querySelector("#window");
const header = document.querySelector("#header2");
const resizeContainer = document.querySelector("#resize-container");
let isDragging = false;
let currentX;
let currentY;
let xOffset = 0;
let yOffset = 0;
let isResizing = false;
let initialX;
let initialY;
let initialWidth;
let initialHeight;
let currentWidth;
let currentHeight;
const minimumWidth = 150;
const minimumHeight = 150;

header.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
header.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
header.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
resizeContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", resizeStart);
resizeContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", resizeEnd);
resizeContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);

function dragStart(e) {
  initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
  initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;

  isDragging = true;
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  isDragging = false;
}

function drag(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (isDragging) {
    currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
    currentY = e.clientY - initialY;

    xOffset = currentX;
    yOffset = currentY;

    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, windowElement);
  }
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
  el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}

function resizeStart(e) {
  initialX = e.clientX;
  initialY = e.clientY;
  initialWidth = windowElement.offsetWidth;
  initialHeight = windowElement.offsetHeight;

  isResizing = true;
}

function resizeEnd(e) {
  isResizing = false;
}

function resize(e) {
  if (isResizing) {
    currentWidth = initialWidth + (e.clientX - initialX);
    currentHeight = initialHeight + (e.clientY - initialY);

    if (currentWidth >= minimumWidth) {
      windowElement.style.width = currentWidth + "px";
    }
    if (currentHeight >= minimumHeight) {
      windowElement.style.height = currentHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}

function closeWindow() {

  const parentElement = document.querySelector("#parent");
  const windowElement = document.querySelector("#window");

  windowElement.style.display = "none";

  setTimeout(() => {

    const newWindow1 = windowElement.cloneNode(true);
    const newWindow2 = windowElement.cloneNode(true);
    const xPos1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (parentElement.offsetWidth - newWindow1.offsetWidth));
    const yPos1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (parentElement.offsetHeight - newWindow1.offsetHeight));
    const xPos2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (parentElement.offsetWidth - newWindow2.offsetWidth));
    const yPos2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (parentElement.offsetHeight - newWindow2.offsetHeight));

    newWindow1.style.display = "";
    newWindow2.style.display = "";
    setTranslate(xPos1, yPos1, newWindow1);
    setTranslate(xPos2, yPos2, newWindow2);
    parentElement.appendChild(newWindow1);
    parentElement.appendChild(newWindow2);
  }, 500);
}

function createWindow() {
  const parentElement = document.querySelector("#parent");

  const windowElement = document.createElement("div");
  let isDragging = false;
  let currentX;
  let currentY;
  let initialX;
  let initialY;
  let xOffset = 0;
  let yOffset = 0;

  function dragStart(e) {
    initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
    initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;

    isDragging = true;
  }

  function dragEnd(e) {
    isDragging = false;
  }

  function drag(e) {
    if (isDragging) {
      e.preventDefault();
      currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.clientY - initialY;

      xOffset = currentX;
      yOffset = currentY;

      setTranslate(currentX, currentY, this.parentNode);
    }
  }

  function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
    el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
  }

  windowElement.classList.add("old-computer-window");
  windowElement.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (parentElement.offsetWidth - 300)) + "px";
  windowElement.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (parentElement.offsetHeight - 300)) + "px";
  windowElement.setAttribute("data-aos", "zoom-in");
  windowElement.setAttribute("data-aos-delay", "300");

  const header = document.createElement("div");
  header.classList.add("header2");
  header.innerHTML = '<p>DANIEL.JPG</p><div class="close" onclick="closeWindow(this)">&#10005;</div>';

  const imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
  imageContainer.classList.add("image-container");

  const resizeContainer = document.createElement("div");
  resizeContainer.classList.add("resize-container");

  windowElement.appendChild(header);
  windowElement.appendChild(imageContainer);
  windowElement.appendChild(resizeContainer);
  parentElement.appendChild(windowElement);

  header.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
  header.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
  header.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
  resizeContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", resizeStart);
  resizeContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", resizeEnd);
  resizeContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
}
```

```css
  #computer-window {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: darkred;
  border-right-color: darkred;
}

#header2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#close-btn {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: darkred;
  border-right-color: darkred;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  border: orange;
}

#window {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 1080px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: #191919;
  border-top-color: #191919;
  border-bottom-color: darkred;
  border-right-color: darkred;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<div data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300" id="parent">
  <div class="old-computer-window" id="window">
    <div class="header2" id="header2">
      <p>DANIEL.JPG</p>
      <div class="close" id="close" onclick="closeWindow()">&#10005;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container"></div>
    <div class="resize-container" id="resize-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is timing. After closing the window and appending the new "windows" you need to add the EventListener again

Comment: you need either add event listeners for new blocks after adding them, or add event listeners on the whole window and look if this is the block you need

Comment: @jollyjoyce1995 in the "function createWindow()" I've already used "addEventListener" right?

Comment: correct me if im missing something but the method `createWindow()` is never called

Comment: @jollyjoyce1995 After the "closeWindow" function I call the "createWindow()" function.

Comment: After the "closeWindow" function you have the "createWindow" function definition. Thats not a call
Function Definition:
`function abc(){
// Do Something
}`
Function call:
`abc();`

Comment: @jollyjoyce1995 Sorry, I don't understand it one bit.

Comment: try adding `createWindow();` after the line:
`parentElement.appendChild(newWindow2);`
in the `closeWindow` method

Comment: @jollyjoyce1995 what that does for me is create 3 windows. One being draggable, but it reacts very slow.

Comment: I tried to rewrite some code, so that you dont have global variables anymore: https://jsitor.com/73OBviORIq
Unfortunatly it isnt perfect, but I dont have time anymore. But it should at least work, besides the resetting to default position after closing the first